# iPhone backup error. What does this mean?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, restore

The iOS was upgraded from 6.1.2 to 6.1.3 and the ADSL disconnected part way through the upgrade and I lost all my contacts, photos, settings etc. Below is the error message that occurs every time I try to restore from my iTunes backup. Even when I try to restore from older backups via Time Machine, this error message still occurs.

**Error message:**

> iTunes could not restore the iPhone "X iPhone" because the backup was
>   corrupt or not compatible with the iPhone that is being restored.

Comment: Since you don't have all the data on your phone now, what about restoring the phone (Settings -> General -> Reset), and then trying?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you already have a valid backup of the iPhone, give [phoneMiner](http://www.amraksoftware.com/) a try (trial download on their site). It will scan for any previous backups and if they exist allow you to extract your contacts/photos etc.